# HoughCircle in openCV detect many circles in a grid?

Tags: opencv

It is a 10x10 grid. It has only 3 circle that I use Paint to draw at (2,4),(6,1) and (10,7). It detects a bunch of circles.
The code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('100-blocks-1.png', 0)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 50, \
    param1 = 50, param2 = 30, minRadius = 0, maxRadius = 0)

cricles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
   cv2.circle(img, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)

  cv2.circle(img, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0,0,255), 3)


cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.imwrite('ahihi.png', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Please help me detect the problem

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should change hough circle parameters. Esecially min radius to, for example 5 pixels.